# Hostname configuration Keycloak 19.0.1

Tags: dns, realm, keycloak

I'm running keycloak version 19.0.1 with no proxy and I want to set a hostname (mykeycloak) as a frontend url to my realm. 
I run the keycloak with the command below:

```
.\kc.bat start-dev --hostname mykeycloak --proxy edge
```

The configuration endpoint (`http://localhost:8080/realms/master/.well-known/uma2-configuration`) shows :

```
{"issuer":"http://mykeycloak/realms/master","authorization_endpoint":"http://mykeycloak/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth",...
```

I also add the below record to my **etc/hosts**:

```
127.0.0.1   mykeycloak
```

Finally when I want to open the mentioned endpoint (`http://mykeycloak/realms/master`)  I face ***This site can’t be reached- ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED***

Am I missing something?

At last, this configuration won't work in a public network unless everyone adds the mykeycloak record to their dns.

So what would be the solution that way?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are simply missing the port, i.e. it should be `http://mykeycloak:8080/realms/master`.

If you want to have keycloak accessible on default ports, e.g. 80 or 443, you either need a proxy running on those ports, forwarding to keycloak on 8080 and 8443, or you run keycloak itself on those ports (but that's a bad idea for security reasons).

Comment: Thanks for your response and sorry for the late reply. I was wondering if you have any suggestions about using proxy (such as nginx) and also hostname at the same time. Now I have a Keycloak behind a nginx proxy but no hostname is defined for the Keycloak. I was wondering which deployment will be better for the production? Thanks in advance.